# Remove Get Variable from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mod_rewrite php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428720/mod-rewrite-php-mysql)

What I want to do is change this:

`www.site.com/profile.php?id=1`

to this:

`www.site.com/profile/Terry_Harvey`

Is there any way to go about doing this?

Comment: This is called "URL Rewriting" ... there are a lot of tutorials about how to do it. Google!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a LOT of things missing in your question. But the final answer would anyway be to look into `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. As for the question, what else would you like to know?

Comment: +1 although I don't really see how `Terry_Harvey` maps to `id=1`

Comment: @AlienWebguy Like I said, LOT of things missing. ;)

Comment: @TerryHarvey check what @AlienWebguy said. Give us more details how the `id` is related to what seems like the `username`.